# How to use Python package sqlite3 'IN'?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I want to select all data of several particular dates using following codes.

```
test_date = ('2012-08-04', '2013-08-19')
conn=sqlite3.connect(sqlite_file)
c=conn.cursor()
dat=c.execute("SELECT dat FROM dat_tbl WHERE date IN ? ", test_date)
dat_tuple=dat.fetchall()
conn.close()
```

It failed with error message

```
OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

I am wondering what is wrong here and how to fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct expression should be,

```
c.execute("SELECT dat FROM dat_tbl WHERE date IN (?, ?)", (date1, date2))
```

question marks should be wrapped with paranthesis.

However, you would also like to [consider using](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/between.php) `BETWEEN`.

**UPDATE**

[string.join(sequence)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) might help you automatically inject question marks to you query.

Consider below,

```
>>> ', '.join(['?']*5)
'?, ?, ?, ?, ?'
```

Thus,

```
>>> "SELECT * FROM example WHERE id in ({0})".format(', '.join(['?'] * len([1,3])))
'SELECT * FROM example WHERE id in (?, ?)'
```

or,

```
>>> q = "SELECT dat FROM dat_tbl WHERE date IN ({0})".format(', '.join(['?'] * len(test_date)))
>>> q
'SELECT dat FROM dat_tbl WHERE date IN (?, ?)'
```

Comment: What if I have 100 dates? Is there an alternative than 100 question marks?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I thought you were be able to handle this to your own. This is beyond of sqlite3 scope - but verily connected to python string manipulation skills.